# If $f$ continuous on topological space, then for all $f(x)$ and open $V$ containing $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I saw this proposition ([https://ece.iisc.ac.in/~parimal/proofs/lecture-17.pdf](https://ece.iisc.ac.in/%7Eparimal/proofs/lecture-17.pdf)), but no proof was offered, as it was claimed obvious. I don't see how this proposition is true for continuous functions over Euclidean spaces even (e.g. cos(x) from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$). Does the proof of the proposition require some restriction of domains?

Edit: Proof was provided of the converse.

Comment: Proposition 1.2 which follows the definition of the statement is a proof? Why did you say that no proof was offered?

Comment: Please make the body of your question self-contained - don't rely on the title to provide essential information.

Comment: The statement should say that $V$ is open (or a neighbourhood of $f(x)$). The lecture notes say that but you have omitted it.

Comment: @copper.hat proof was provided of the converse

Comment: @RobArthan the forward direction still works without the openness condition. I am not attempting to prove the biconditional version as the converse already had a proof in the link provided

Comment: No: take your space to be $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Take $f$ to be the identity function and take $V = \{x\}$ for some $x$ of your choice. then $f^{-1}(V) = \{x\}$ is not a neighbourhood of $x$. (And please edit your question so the body is self-contained - that might give you a good opportunity for you to review what you actually said in your question.)

Comment: Specifically, the statement you wrote in the title is not the "converse" that you meant to write.

Comment: @RobArthan Changed to include open.

Comment: OK. But the main content of your question is still in the title and not the body. Please try to avoid that in future: I suggest writing the body of your question first and then composing the title when you are happy with your question (like a journalist who writes a self-contained article with the expectation that a sub-editor will write the headline that summarises it).

Comment: And after all that, what is your actual problem? The lecture notes look good to me as they did to @copper.hat.

Comment: @RobArthan The second line of the proof states $f^{-1}(V)$ contains $x$ without offering proof. That is what Iam confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuout and $V$ is open, the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is open as well, by definition of continuity (I am using the definition in the notes you linked to). Moreover, we know $f(x)\in V$, so $x\in f^{-1}(V)$. (In detail: by definition, $f^{-1}(V)=\{y|f(y)\in V\}$; we know $f(x)\in V$, so $x\in f^{-1}(V)$). Therefore $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and contains $x$, which means it is a neighbourhood of $x$.